# How to use a kotlin constant in spring spel expression

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-el

I try to create a KafkaListener in Kotlin with

`@KafkaListener(topics = "<TOPIC_NAME>")`

For  I want to use a kotlin constant

I tried to access it with:

`@KafkaListener(topics = "\${T(package.name.Class).CONST}")`

kotlin class:

```
package package.name

class Class{
  companion object{
    const val CONST = "desired-topic-name"
  }
}
```

I'm getting a "Could not resolve placeholder" error message but would expect to use the constant

Comment: Can you try adding `@JvmField` annotation to `CONST`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#` instead of `$`. `$` is a simple property placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking way too far:

In the end I just used

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${package.name.Class.CONST}"
```

and it works like a charm